# What is the difference between "No problem!" and "No sweat!"?

Tags: phrases, word-usage

Is it possible to say "No sweat!" instead of "No problem!?

Comment: Both mean the same thing.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. It's also possible to say "Rubber baby buggy bumpers" instead of "She sells seashells by the seashore." The difference being that, in your case, the two phrases you have listed mean more or less the same thing and can be considered essentially interchangeable.

Comment: One small difference is that, while 'No sweat' is very informal and [I imagine] used mainly between native speakers, 'no problem' seems to have very wide usage and is also used to replace 'You're welcome' when you thank someone.

Comment: Unless you are someone who is so attractive that even your sweat is attractive, stick with "no problem" or even "you're welcome."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two expressions convey the same meaning, *no sweat* is  more informal and according to Etymonline its usage predates that of *no problem* of a few years. I'd add that the *no problem* is a more common expression than *no sweat*:

***[No sweat](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=sweat&allowed_in_frame=0)***:

> - Colloquial no sweat "no problem" ***attested from 1963.***

***[No problem](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=problem&allowed_in_frame=0)***:

> - Response no problem "that is acceptable; that can be done without difficulty" is ***recorded from 1968.***

From *usacademy.collegenet.com:*

> - "[No sweat](https://usacademy.collegenet.com/magnoliaPublic/preview/preview-learn/culture/American-Expressions-and-American-Culture/american-language/n/no-sweat.html)" isn't an impolite phrase, but it's a bit "earthy" for polite conversation - and at the same time, it's a little bit dated as a saying, something older Americans might use more than students do.  You might want to use "no problem" if you are talking to someone you don't know well, or the popular phrase "piece of cake."